# Why does TypeScript infer a wider type for a generic parameter with a default, instead of extends?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type ConfigItem<T, U> = {
  label: T;
  value: U
}
class A<T extends string, U extends string, M extends ConfigItem<T, U>> {
  optData: M[] = [];
  constructor(data: M[]) {
    this.optData = data;
  }

  addItem(data: M) {
    this.optData.push(data)
  }
}

const a = new A([{label: '1', value: '1'}])
console.log(a.optData)
a.addItem({label: '3', value:'2'}); // ERROR: Type '"3"' is not assignable to type '"1"'
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WyQnKW)

But when I change `M extends` to `M =` , the error is gone:

```
type ConfigItem<T, U> = {
  label: T;
  value: U
}
class A<T extends string, U extends string, M = ConfigItem<T, U>> {
  optData: M[] = [];
  constructor(data: M[]) {
    this.optData = data;
  }

  addItem(data: M) {
    this.optData.push(data)
  }
}

const a = new A([{label: '1', value: '1'}])
a.addItem({label: '3', value:'2'}) // OK!
```

[Plyaground](https://tsplay.dev/WvQ6rm)

Why TypeScript inferred a wider type when generic parameter got default value in above code?

Update:
I understand that the `extends` impose constraint on the type parameter and `default` doesn't.
What I want to known is why and how TypeScript infer the types from the arguments of the constructor of class A in above 2 cases. Why it's narrowed to literal type '1' in `extends` case rather than type string?

Comment: Why are you using `extends`? What are you planning to do? In the above example, I don't really see a point in A being generic if you know that T and U are strings...

Comment: @Shai U and U may be subsets of string

Comment: Extends specifies a type constraint, an upper bound, on the type parameter. Defaults specify a tape argument with which to instantiate the type parameter when the collar does not provide one. They have completely different purposes